# Gridview - Update exception

Tags: ms-access, gridview

I am trying to perform UPDATE action in Gridview(ASP.net). I have created a AccessDataSource and included all the queries in it. *Delete, Select* queries work well but not the *UPDATE*

I get the error "*Syntax error in Update statement*". My query is

```
UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = @RateCenterName, 
State/Province = @State/Province, Quantity/Threshold = @Quantity/Threshold 
WHERE RateCenterID = @RateCenterID
```

I realized from a site that '[]' should be used if the query has special characters like "/"

So I have changed the query to

```
UPDATE RateCenters SET [RateCenterName] = [RateCenterName], [State/Province] = [State/Province], [Quantity/Threshold] = [Quantity/Threshold] WHERE RateCenterID = RateCenterID.
```

Now I am not getting any error on UPDATE action but the data is not getting updated

**This is my html code**

```
 <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/db1.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM RateCenters" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM RateCenters WHERE RateCenterID = @RateCenterID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO RateCenters ([RateCenterID], [RateCenterName], [State/Province], [Quantity/Threshold]) VALUES ([RateCenterID], [RateCenterName], [State/Province], [Quantity/Threshold])" 

            UpdateCommand="UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = @RateCenterName, State[/]Province = @State[/]Province, Quantity[/]Threshold = Quantity[/]Threshold WHERE RateCenterID = @RateCenterID">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Kindly let me know the problem

Thanks

Arjun

Comment: Are these State/Province and Quantity/Threshold column names?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826763

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo: yeah State/Province and Quantity/Threshold are column names and it is difficult for me to change it now..its a client's task

Comment: I changed the query to                                           UPDATE RateCenters SET [RateCenterName] = [RateCenterName], [State/Province] = [State/Province], [Quantity/Threshold] = [Quantity/Threshold] WHERE RateCenterID = RateCenterID.                    Now I am not getting any error on update action but the data is not getting updated

Comment: Could you provide code that prepare sql statement and parameters.. and execute.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick write up

UpdateCommand="UPDATE RateCenters SET RateCenterName = @RateCenterName, [State/Province] = @State, [Quantity/Threshold] = @Quantity WHERE RateCenterID = @RateCenterID">

Comment: Thank you Rashmi! Perfect answer. Am extremely happy now!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use / in your column names... U can use [ ] to block ur column names...

```
UPDATE RateCenters SET [RateCenterName] = [RateCenterName], [State/Province] = [State/Province], [Quantity/Threshold] = [Quantity/Threshold] WHERE RateCenterID = RateCenterID.
```

it actually updated but with the same data thats why it wasnt visible... =)

e.g

```
[Quantity/Threshold] = [Quantity/Threshold]
```

this will just reassign it to itself =)

Comment: That will probably not work, either. The slash is not a good idea.

Comment: I realized from a site that '[]' should be used if the query has special characters like "/"                         So I have changed my query and updated in my question